# Is it possible to create a class or interface that inherit all properties of a type

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, typescript-typings

Let's say I have a type

```
type A = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
};
```

Is there any way to create an equivalent interface, like

```
interface B {
    a: string,
    b: string,
}
```

without having to rewrite everything from above.

And is there any way to do the same with class, but with some default assignments, like

```
class C {
    a: '',
    b: '',
}
```

So we can use `new C()` and don't have to rewrite `A`

If it is not possible, which is the best way to write `class C` base on what we have already defined in `type A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `extends`:

```
type A = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
};

interface B extends A { // <-- { a: string; b: string; c: string; }
    c: string;
}
```

For your second question, you can kind of use implements but it will only copy the typings so you must provide a value:

```
class C implements A {
  a: '';
  b: '';
}
```

Comment: The interface part is good. But the class part is not working. I assume that you want to write a = '', b = ''. Anyway it needs to rewrite both ```a``` and ```b```, which I want to avoid

Comment: **you can kind of use implements but it will only copy the typings so you must provide a value** yeah I covered that in my response, that's all you can do what you want is not possible. It's a lot better for classes with complex typings, especially for methods with multiple overloads

Comment: you could use a base class and extend that though. but you can't do it with interfaces

Comment: I know why should I use a class. The thing here is I want to inherit the keys from another class, so that I used type Pick, I want to take it back to a class. That's why I have this question

Comment: if you want to inherit keys from a class use extends

Comment: Note that I only want to reuse ```key``` but not ```type``` of those keys. So I can't extends

Comment: I used Record<keyof Pick<A, 'a' | 'b'>, boolean> but then it became a type, not a class anymore

Comment: right, types and values are not interchangeable. I'm not sure what sort of edge use case you're dealing with but as far as I know the only way to turn a type into a class is via `implements`, and any extension of an implemented class will have the same typings. I do not think this is possible what you are looking for.

Comment: I think so too, but let wait to see if there's any solution that we haven't thought about :D